# file upload form requires two submits

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form for uploading images to the server...

For some reason the form will only submit if I click the submit button twice. It just hangs after the first click of the submit button...

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
<form method="post" action="photoUpload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Image 1:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is there anything else on the page? Any JavaScript?

Comment: Nothing jumps off the page at me.  Is there any JS or perhaps some broken HTML somewhere else in the page involved?

Comment: That's it... nothing else on the page! It's bizarre hey!

Comment: Also, does it not even try to make the request if you only press it once, or is it hanging?  A lot more debugging needs to happen on your end before we can help.

Comment: It just hangs... sorry, was meant to mention that

Comment: Are you sure it hangs forever?  How large of image is it?  It may just be taking a minute to finish.  Have you watched the request in the Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug?

Comment: Add you PHP - lets see what your doing on the backend

Comment: ha! ok, so I've tried it with firebug and I can't replicate the problem now!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no problem with your form. It's absolutely ok.
If possible just cut all the entire form & paste it once again. Hope it will work.

I have a demo below please follow:-

```
<form method="post" action="Mytest.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">My File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```